# Get previous and following sentences in spaCy

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I am using spaCy to process sentences of a doc. Given one sentence, I'd like to get the previous and following sentence.

I can easily iterate over the sentences of the doc as following:

```
nlp_content = nlp(content)
sentences = nlp_content.sents
for idx, sent in enumerate(sentences):
```

But I can't get the sentence #idx-1 or #idx+1 from the sentence #idx.

Is there any function or property that could be useful there?

Thanks!

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in sentence index. You would need to iterate over the sentences once to create your own list of sentence spans to access them this way.

```
sentence_spans = tuple(doc.sents) # alternately: list(doc.sents)
```